# Downloading Rss Feed in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, rss, urllib2, urllib

I have a scenario where I need to download the xml of the provided url of rss feed.

I am using following code for the same:

```
urls = ['http://static.espncricinfo.com/rss/livescores.xml', 'http://ibnlive.in.com/ibnrss/top.xml']   

for rssUrl in urls:
    if rssUrl is not None:
        dom = parse(urllib.urlopen(rssUrl))
        tmp = dom.toprettyxml()
```

When I am running this as an independent application it is running fine without any issue.

But when I am calling this code from a websocket application there is no consistency in the execution of the code.

Some times it works properly and some times it doesn't. Plus this behavior is random. Please can any one tell what may be the reason behind it?

The error shown is:-

```
<urlopen error [Errno 66] unknown>
```

I have tried using **urllib2** instead of **urllib**. But the problem persists.

Comment: "Some times it works properly and some times it doesn't" - what do you mean by that? what's the error ? can you provide a URL to reproduce ?

Comment: Both urls work great. If you don't intend to publish a full reproducible example I'm afraid you won't get help.

Comment: how do you setup your websocket application (which library)

Comment: I am using the ws4py library to setup my websocket

Comment: do you use tornado or gevent ?

Comment: which os do you use ?

Comment: I am using gevent. My OS is Windows.